# How to URL Decode in iOS - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, urldecode

The stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding method is not working properly as it's not decoding special symbols that dont start with a % character, i.e., the + character.  Does anyone know of a better method to do this in iOS?

Here's what I'm currently using:

```
NSString *path = [@"path+with+spaces"
     stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And here's an example of the output:

path+with+spaces

Comment: Can you please post your code or an example of where and how that method is not working properly for you?

Comment: but what i'm trying to do is apply a php-like urldecode() function that will recover the original structure of the file names.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[@"path+with+spaces"
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]
    stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Note that the plus-for-space substitution is only used in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data - the query string part of a URL, or the body of a `POST` request.

Comment: there are other characters other that the + that need to be decoded, no?

Comment: When I tried to decode a string @"abcjhjhdfjhafjakhfjaklfj12346890(*^$#@@@#$%^^     ........", using this method, it returns nil. It looks like stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding is causing some problems because of "Returns nil if the transformation is not possible (i.e. the percent escapes give a byte sequence not legal in the given encoding). " (from NSURL.h). So just a heads up for those that ran into this issue making a category like me.

Comment: `%^^` isn't a valid percent-escape.

Answer (score 20):

```
// Decode a percent escape encoded string.
- (NSString*) decodeFromPercentEscapeString:(NSString *) string {
return (__bridge NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL,
                                                        (__bridge CFStringRef) string,
                                                        CFSTR(""),
                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}
```

http://cybersam.com/ios-dev/proper-url-percent-encoding-in-ios

This seems to be the preferred way because...
"Apparently" this is a "bug" apple is aware of, but they haven't done anything about it yet...  ( http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/ )

Comment: Perfect! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to replace the plus sign with percent escapes, perform a string replacement from "+" to " " (single space). Then use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` to add the percent escapes.

The plus sign is one of many reserved URL characters that is never encoded.

(`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` decodes the percent escapes)

Answer (score 1):

swift 2 :

```
extension String  {

    func uriDecodedString() -> String? {
       return self.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: " ").stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the PercentEncoder library from Cocoapods.

**Swift 4**

- Include the library to your Podfile:

  pod PercentEncoder
- Import the library PercentEncoder

  **import PercentEncoder**

  class ViewController{

  ...

  }
- Replace the "+" character by "%20" and use the method "ped_decodeURI"

  "path+with+spaces".replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%20").ped_decodeURI()

It will return "path with spaces"

Here the link for reference: https://cocoapods.org/pods/PercentEncoder