# AFNetworking received non-English character: how to convert?

Tags: json, encoding, nsstring, afnetworking, jsonkit

I am getting JSON response from some web server, say the server returns:

```
"kən.grætju'leiʃən"
```

I use AFNetworking and JSONKit, but what I've received is:

```
"&#230;m'bi&#643;&#601;n"
```

Not sure if it's AFNetworking's problem or JSONKit's problem, but any way, how to I parse and convert the string so it looks the same as from server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The server may be returning characters encoded in a way that violates the official JSON spec.  If those characters are encoded as escaped unicode IDs (like `\U1234`) then JSONKit and NSJSONSerialization should both handle them fine.

If you can't change the server, you can work around the issue by URL-decoding the string - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10691541/1445366 for some code to handle it.  But if your server isn't following the correct specs, you're likely to run into other issues.