# Unable to decode a javascript escaped string which contains japanese text in iOS ObjectiveC

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, decoding

I am getting the below string n cookies from a UIWebview which is javascript escaped.

```
"%7B%27status%27%20%3A%20400%2C%20%27message%27%20%3A%20%27%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8%u30E1%u30C3%u30BB%u30FC%u30B8%27"
```

I am using the below function to get unescaped string.

```
NSString *decodeString = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
decodeString = [decodeString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];
```

The expected output is

```
"{'status' : 400, 'message' : 'テストメッセージ'}"
```

but `*decodeString` is coming as `nil`

What is the proper way to decode.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this => http://stackoverflow.com/a/10691541/1155650

Comment: I tried this. But I am getting null.

Comment: @LeenaPatel  when i tested it with `"%7B%27status%27%20%3A%20400%2C%20%27message%27%20%3A%20%27"` string means before %u ....it works fine...but when I add the string after %u it give nil...means problem is `%u30B9%u30C8%u30E1%u30C3%u30BB%u30FC%u30B` data

Comment: @Bhavin while sending the japanese message from server side, "テストメッセージ" is converting to "%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8%u30E1%u30C3%u30BB%u30FC%u30B8" and After that its doing UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Yes . If message will be in english, I am able to decode it using NSUTF8Encoding. But for Japanese message, Its giving nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first quick solution is separe utf charts and unicode charts, like this:

```
NSString *string = @"%7B%27status%27%20%3A%20400%2C%20%27message%27%20%3A%20%27%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8%u30E1%u30C3%u30BB%u30FC%u30B8%27";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"%27message%27(.*)%27" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);

NSString *decodeString = [modifiedString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", decodeString);
```

Better will be use this:

```
NSString *str = @"%7B%27status%27%20%3A%20400%2C%20%27message%27%20%3A%20%27%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8%u30E1%u30C3%u30BB%u30FC%u30B8%27";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%u" withString:@"\\u"];
NSString *convertedStr = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",convertedStr);
```

in this case is output:

```
{'status' : 400, 'message' : '\u30C6\u30B9\u30C8\u30E1\u30C3\u30BB\u30FC\u30B8'
```

in this case you must procees unicode charts .... i hope this help.