# Swift: Change JSON formatted NSURLRequest to String

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurl

What I am doing is shipping a JSON structured string on NSULRRequest, getting rid of the urlscheme prefix, serialize it to JSON and then whatever I can do with it.

```
urlscheme://{"Type":"photo","Name":"Photo13"}
```

So I changed NSURLRequest to string by doing

```
    let url = request.URL
    let string = "\(url)"
    print(string)
```

but the string appears like

```
urlscheme://%7B%22Type%22:%22photo%22,%22Name%22:%22Photo13%22%7D
```

So I have to change it by invoking stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString over and over on all possible changes.

```
replacedString = replacedString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%7B",
        withString: "{",
        options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch,
        range: nil)
.
..
...
```

Is there a better way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've got there is a [percent encode string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). This is done because certain characters have special meanings within a URL. The NSString method `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` will convert a percent encode string back to a normal string for you.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920071/how-to-url-decode-in-ios-objective-c)

Comment: Thank you. Xcode7 just let me know that method is now deprecated and     use stringByRemovingPercentEncoding instead.